# Vampire V5 Old Tremere

Tags: house-rules, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

Vampire 5th changed a lot about clan flaws and even more about the Tremere. Now, since we want to play the new system in the Dark Ages as well, I'll definitely need to have an alternative flaw for times before the Pyramid crushed.

I want it to scale with the other flaws and bane severity. The current model is: After establishing the blood bond with three drinks, Tremere start on a one higher Bond Strengh than usual - meaning with Bane Severity 1 they start at 4, with 2 it will be 5 and so on.
We decided against lowering the amount of drinks necessary because we couldn't find a solution for Severity 3 and also a single drink felt a bit harsh.

We also thought about adding the "Long Bond" flaw on top.

Has anyone here found a solution for their group already? Otherwise I'd be happy about feedback or alternative ideas.